Error C2440 Using std::make_shared in Visual Studio
I am probably making some elementary error here, but google has turned up nothing. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and my code is the following:
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<double[]> sp7 = std::make_shared<double[]>(256, 2.0);
}

I took this directly from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared so I have reason to believe it is correct. Nevertheless when I compile I get
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from '_Ux (*const )' to 'double *'

Double clicking this error takes me into the guts of some function template called _Set_ptr_rep_and_enable_shared, which doesn't tell me much. The full build output is
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Mem, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Mem.cpp
1>C:\[MSVCdir]\include\xmemory(1893,9): warning C4200: nonstandard extension used: zero-sized array in struct/union
1>C:\[MSVCdir]\include\xmemory(1893,9): message : This member will be ignored by a defaulted constructor or copy/move assignment operator
1>C:\[MSVCdir]\include\memory(2027): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Wrap<_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=double []
1>        ]
1>C:\[MSVCdir]\include\memory(2725): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Ref_count_obj2<_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=double []
1>        ]
1>C:\[localdir]\Test\Mem\Mem.cpp(5): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<double []> std::make_shared<double[],int,double>(int &&,double &&)' being compiled
1>C:\[MSVCdir]\include\memory(1770,1): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from '_Ux (*const )' to 'double *'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ux=double []
1>        ]
1>C:\[MSVCdir]\include\memory(1770,22): message : Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>C:\[MSVCdir]\include\memory(2725): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr<double []>::_Set_ptr_rep_and_enable_shared<_Ty>(_Ux (*const ),std::_Ref_count_base *const ) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=double [],
1>            _Ux=double []
1>        ]
1>C:\[MSVCdir]\include\memory(2728): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::shared_ptr<double []>::_Set_ptr_rep_and_enable_shared<_Ty>(_Ux (*const ),std::_Ref_count_base *const ) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=double [],
1>            _Ux=double []
1>        ]
1>C:\[localdir]\Test\Mem\Mem.cpp(5): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::shared_ptr<double []> std::make_shared<double[],int,double>(int &&,double &&)' being compiled
1>Done building project "Mem.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========


Have you set the appropriate standard? This is in C++20.

Have you enabled C++20?  Per your link this only works in c++20+

How does one enable C++20?

In the properties for the project under General change C++ Language Standard to C++ 20. Be sure to check the Configuration and Platforms items at the top of the dialog to be sure you're changing it for the correct configuration or set them both to All to change it for all of them.

Thanks to those who noted that enabling the latest version of C++ fixes this issue.
